# How to target LLVM from a compiler written in F#?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, f#, llvm

I'm part way through writing a toy language in F#. I want to target LLVM, but it looks like I'll have to do some work to make that happen.

It looks like I might be able to do some interop with the IRBuilder libraries, or I might be able to roll my own IR emitter. As far as I've searched, I couldn't find any solution that anyone else has made.

How might I do this?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question, please explain.

Comment: SO is not the place for What is the best way type questions - this is probably better suited to the LLVM mailing list

Comment: @John So if I asked how I would do this, without making note of any of the ways that I thought might work, that would make this question better? i.e. if it were "How would I target LLVM from a compiler written in F#?"

Comment: Even then that is probably to broad - SO questions are best when they are like: I tried to do `x` - here is my code `...` but this part gives me a compiler/runtime error

Comment: @JohnPalmer: Gotta disagree with that statement. Promoting questions like that turns SO into a group debugging center, with little chance of the questions being useful for others. Questions more along these lines, on the other hand, will serve as useful sources of information for future searchers with similar goals.

Comment: I sincerely think the paragraph you've removed greatly improves the quality of this question. I'm not going to make my reopen vote provisional on its inclusion (I've already cast the vote), but I'd like to urge you to replace that info, along with any other relevant details. Who knows but that you may attract even more info despite your already-accepted answer?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Done, though I'm hesitant considering the discussion happening right now regarding the quality of the question as it was initially.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know several people who use F# + LLVM regularly, and I've seen a bunch of questions about it here on SO before:
[Questions tagged F# and LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23+llvm?sort=votes)

Anyway, take a look at the [LLVM bindings for F#](https://github.com/fsharp/llvm-fs) on Github -- that should be a good starting point.

Comment: Didn't think to search with [tags]; thanks also for the Github link.

Comment: See also [Basic use of LLVM from F#](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2012/11/basic-use-of-llvm-from-f.html) – it's not free, but it sounds like exactly what is being looked for.

Answer (score 1):

[LLVMSharp](https://github.com/Microsoft/LLVMSharp) seems to be a viable solution.
They have a [C# tutorial](http://ice1000.org/llvm-cs/en/) to build a language on top of LLVM that should be easy to convert to F#.